# Parametrierbarkeit

Tags: translation, word-usage

Was ist mit dem Ausdruck "eine *parametrierbare* Motorleistung" genau gemeint? (Es handelt sich um eine technische Übersetzung ins Englische.) Ist es einfach nur ein möglicher (einstellbarer) Wert für die Motorleistung? Ich suche ein passendes englisches Wort - "configurable" ist falsch glaube ich (Werte können nicht konfiguriert werden, Geräte und Computersysteme schon); vielleicht "settable" oder "adjustable"?

Comment: Mich würde bei diesem Thema auch interessieren, was denn der Unterschied zwischen "parametrierbar" und "parametrisierbar" ist.

Comment: Soso. Du sucht in einem **DEUTSCH**-Forum ein passendes **ENGLISCHES** Wort? Dir ist aber schon klar, dass das hier off-topic ist, oder? Wenn du ein englisches Wort suchst, dann frage bitte in http://english.stackexchange.com oder in http://ell.stackexchange.com nach.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Beachte, dass Übersetzungsfragen ins Englische durchaus on-topic sein können, und zwar, wenn es das Verstehen bzw. Erfassen des deutschen Begriffs eine Schwierigkeit darstellt. Wann genau das gegeben ist, ist im Einzelfall zu entscheiden, aber pauschal off-topic sind solche Fragen nicht. (Und nebenbei ist das alles kein Grund zu schreien.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because wrong language site.

Comment: Du stellst eigentlich zwei Fragen. Willst Du vor allem wissen, was der Begriff genau bedeutet? Wie würde Dir eine englische Übersetzung dabei helfen?

Comment: Da mir der Begriff „parametrierbar“ nicht bekannt ist, würde mir eine englische Übersetzung wahrscheinlich auch helfen.

Answer (score 0):

Wenn ich beim Autofahren mehr Gas gebe, verändere ich die Eingangsparameter, indem mehr Benzin in den Motor gespritzt wird. Die Leistung des Motors ist also parametrierbar.

Ich glaube `adjustable` oder `configurable` würde sehr gut passen.
Vielleicht wäre auch `configurable via engine parameter` denkbar.