# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "parametrieren" und "parametrisieren"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25350/parametrierbarkeit) kam der Begriff *parametrierbare Motorleistung* auf. Ich hatte *parametrieren* noch nie gehört, und kenne nur *parametrisieren* (also: mit (veränderbaren) Parametern versehen). Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/parametrieren) bestägt, dass es *parametrieren* gibt, und ergänzt "Gebrauch: besonders Elektrotechnik, Kfz-Technik".

Was ist also genau der Unterschied zwischen *parametrieren* und *parametrisieren*? Bedeuten sie vielleicht dasselbe, und unterscheiden sich nur im Sprachgebrauch des Anwendungsgebiets?

Wenn es so ist, wie ist dieser Unterschied entstanden? Möglicherweise ähnlich wie bei *edieren* und *editieren*? Gibt es weitere Beispiele für solche Paare?

Comment: Diese Quelle behauptet einen Bedeutungsunterschied: http://geekswithblogs.net/mapfel/archive/2009/03/16/130120.aspx

Comment: @chirlu Gut gefunden!

Comment: @chirlu: Allerdings verstehe ich dann nicht, wie Bedeutung "Versehen dieser Parameter mit Werten" mit "parametrierbare Motorleisung" zusammenhängt. Müsste es dann nicht "parametrisierbare Motorleistung", aber z.B. "wie haben in diesem Testlauf die Moterleistung wie folgt parametriert" heißen?

Answer (score 9):

> Parametrisieren: Versehen eines Objekts|Modells|etc. mit Parametern

So weit wie ich das verstehe, bedeutet `parametrisieren` jetzt an dein Beispiel angelehnt, der Motorleistung Parameter hinzuzufügen.

> Parametrieren: Versehen dieser Parameter mit Werten

`parametrieren` jedoch bedeutet die Parameter anzupassen. Also die Werte der verschiedenen Parameter zu verändern.

EDIT:

Scheinbar werden die beiden Wörter je nach Fachgebiet unterschiedlich verwendet und haben manchmal auch die gleiche Bedeutung:

> Unter einer **Parameterdarstellung (auch Parametrisierung oder Parametrierung)** versteht man in der Mathematik eine Darstellung, bei der die Punkte einer Kurve oder Fläche als Funktion einer oder mehrerer Variablen, der Parameter, durchlaufen werden. Für die Beschreibung einer Kurve in der Ebene oder im Raum wird ein Parameter benötigt, für die Beschreibung einer Fläche ein Satz von zwei Parametern.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterdarstellung)

Wobei **parametrieren** bevorzugt in der Elektrotechnik und Kfz-Technik verwendet wird,

> **pa­ra­me­t­rie­ren**
>
> Wortart: schwaches Verb
>
> **Gebrauch: besonders Elektrotechnik, Kfz-Technik**

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/parametrieren)

Comment: Warum wird dann aber "parametrierbare Motorleistung" statt "parametriesierbare Motorleistung" oder "parametrisierte Motorleistung" verwendet? Und wenn man nach "parametrieren" oder "parametrierbar" googlet, warum sind die Ergebnisse meist aus der Kfz- oder Elektrotechnik, während die Ergebnisse für "parametrisierbar" eher aus der Informatik oder Mathematik sind? Wenn ich höre "parametrisierte Motorleistung", denke ich als Informatiker/Mathematiker "ich kann Parameter einstellen, von denen die Motorleistung abhängt". Die Kfz-Mechaniker nennen das aber offenbar "parametrierbare Motorleistung".

Comment: Parametrisierungen in der Mathematik sind nicht nur auf die Fälle Kurven und Flächen beschränkt. Viel allgemeiner kann es sich um ein komplexes Modell, also um eine große Anzahl von Gleichungen und viele Parameter handeln. Weiterhin: Es ist nicht ungewöhnlich, daß verschiedene Gruppen von Wissenschaftlern Gleiches mit unterschiedlichen Fachbegriffen bezeichnen. Ein gutes Beispiel dazu aus der Signalverarbeitung  ist das _Glossary_, das Palle Jorgensen seinem Buch _Analysis and Probability Wavelets, Signals, Fractals_ vorangestellt hat. (Sind in einem Komm. Anlagen möglich? Könnte Gloss. anh.)

Comment: Elektroingenieur hier, der in der Uni auch mit viel Mathematik beschäftigt war: _parametrieren_ ist in der Elektrotechnik definitiv gängig und meiner Erfahrung nach auch wesentlich gebräuchlicher als _parametrisieren_. Aufgrund der Ähnlichkeit der Wörter würde ich von Kolleg/inn/en auch erwarten, beides gleichbedeutend zu verstehen und mich umgekehrt nicht darauf verlassen, dass ein u.U. theoretisch vorhandener Unterschied in der Bedeutung allgemein bekannt wäre. Der Duden verweist für die Bedeutung von [parametrieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/parametrieren) auf parametrisieren.

Answer (score -4):

Parametrisieren ist als Begriff schwer nachvollziehbar, dann müsste man auch "telefonisieren" statt telefonieren und "quadrisieren" statt quadrieren.
Wäre schön wenn das Unding "Parametrisieren" einfach eliminiert würde.

Parameter werden parametriert, Punkt.

Comment: Wird, daraus folgend, mit einem *Editor* dann *ediert*?

Comment: Und Straßenbahnen sind wohl elektriert, Medien digitaliert, Sie vielseitig interiert und Ihr Haar friert ... Oder haben Sie gar nur fantiert, um Ihre überschüssige Kreativität zu kanalieren?

Comment: @Björn Friedrich wenn Sie so weitermachen wird Sie noch ein Mod verwarnisieren.